# SAPUI5 / OpenUI5 Logging

Tags: logging, sapui5

Is it possible to make the framework print output of `jQuery.sap.log.*` functions to standard browser console without opening SAP Diagnostics window?

According to OpenUI [Logging and Tracing](https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/9f4d62c6648a423d85aaf2bfc2c7ddfe.html) of Developer Guide it should work without opening Diagnistics, but it isn't working, at least within Chrome Dev 48.0.2564.116 m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The framework prints all log statements that are within the current loglevel.

I think by default that is ERROR, therefore you should see red error messages originating from UI5 in your console if there are errors.

To enable other messages, adapt the loglevel to the level that you need by running (for example):

```
jQuery.sap.log.setLevel(jQuery.sap.log.Level.DEBUG);
```

Also see: https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.log.html#.setLevel

Comment: In addition you can use `jQuery.sap.log.setLevel(someLevel, "myContext")` to create a new logging-context. You can use this context to specify different log-levels within one application: `jQuery.sap.log.debug("myLogMessage, "someDetailMessage", "myContext")`

Comment: I found it convenient to set logging level with Tampermonkey user script, as this allows get desired result without code modification.

Comment: jQuery.sap.log is deprecated since openui5 1.58. It has been replaced by sap/base/Log: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/module%3Asap%2Fbase%2FLog